# how can I strip the filename from a path in tcsh?

Tags: path, tcsh

Given this variable in tcsh:

```
set i = ~/foo/bar.c
```

how can I get just the directory part of `$i`?

```
~/foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your system provides a 'dirname' command you could:

```
set i = `dirname ~/foo/bar.c`
echo $i
```

Note the missing $ in front of the variable name. This solution is shell agnostic though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is something different from above:
Available in tcsh but few other shells AFAIK

```
> set i = ~/foo/bar.c
> echo ${i:t}
bar.c
> echo ${i:h}
/home/erflungued/foo
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I found to do it while waiting for answers here:

```
set i = ~/foo/bar.c
echo $i:h
```

result:

```
~/foo
```

Answer (score 1):

For completely, getting the file name is accomplished with the basename command:

```
set j = `basename ~/foo/bar.c`
echo $j
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dirname` command, for example:

```
set i = `dirname "~/foo/bar.c"`
```

Notice the quotation marks around path. It's important to include them. If you skip the quotation marks, `dirname` will fail for paths which contain spaces. Mind that `~/` expression evaluates before `dirname` is executed, thus even such simple example may fail if quotation marks are not used and home path includes spaces.

Of course the same problem applies also to all other commands, it's good practice to **always** surround argument to a command with quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $i | awk -F"/" '{$NF="";print}' OFS="/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dirname "$i"` indeed, and not `${i:h}`.

The latter does not produce the intended result if `$i` contains only a file name (no path), while `dirname` correctly returns the current directory `.` in that case.

```
> set i = bar.c
> echo ${i:h}
bar.c
> dirname "$i"
.
```